# Why word2bits RAM usage like word2vec?

Tags: word2vec

I am using word2bits for large datasets. Actually, what I observed was word2bits occupying RAM like word2vec. So, I thought that what will happen for a small dataset.

Because of this purpose, I ran the word2bits example which mentioned in Readme (https://github.com/agnusmaximus/Word2Bits).I observed the RAM usage in htop.
[image]

When I ran this text8 on word2vec. It is also occupying the same RAM.

Comment: Both image and question needs more clarity.

Comment: I changed the image @tiredandboreddev

Comment: Just guessing here, but for a smallish dataset like `text8`, other things likely dominate memory usage. Try larger datasets, and some more accurate way of sampling RAM usage (such as each language/runtime's native method of reporting process size, at the moment of peak usage when training is done), to see if there's a real difference. (Trying to catch glimpses of readouts from external tools at just the right time is much harder to compare or rely upon.)

Comment: @gojomo Finally I got an answer. This issue was solved in the GitHub issues (https://github.com/agnusmaximus/Word2Bits/issues/7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word2bits use RAM like word2vec. This issue was solved in the GitHub issues (github.com/agnusmaximus/Word2Bits/issues/7)